# How can I find a textbook that will give a good treatment of a given topic?

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request

This question has both a specific and a general piece to it.

Firstly, the specifics: I am looking for a good reference with a discussion of the Perron-Frobenius Theorem, in particular the Frobenius part for irreducible non-negative matrices (My level is after my second year of university. I have taken a second course in linear algebra, but that did not cover the PF theorem.)

Secondly, I would like to extend this question to something a bit more general. This is hardly the first time I have been scrambling to find a reference on something on short notice (for instance, I am doing research this summer, and the professor I am working with expected I would have covered a few topics which I have not actually covered). I often find that papers are too brief and to the point compared to textbooks, where there is more of a discussion and motivation to the theorem. So, my question is as follows: If I need a textbook reference on some given topic, what is the best way to go about finding one?

Comment: I can't help you with the first question, sorry, but maybe it helps you with the second question if I say that I usually know very quickly if a book is a good one for my needs by just checking superficially how the introduction is written, how it is structured and what the tone is like in a few short proofs. Typically, I take 5-8 books on the broad topic that look likeable from the shelf in the library and check the aspects I just mentioned. Most of the time I'm happy with the book that's left after this "casting". And I agree, papers are almost always very bad references...

Answer (score 0):

Two books are—

- Gantmacher, Felix (2000), *[The Theory of Matrices](https://books.google.com/books?id=cyX32q8ZP5cC&lpg=PA178&vq=preceding%20section&pg=PA53#v=onepage&q&f=false),* Volume 2, AMS Chelsea Publishing, ISBN 0-8218-2664-6.
- Meyer, Carl (2000), *[Matrix analysis and applied linear algebra](https://web.archive.org/web/20100307021652/http://www.matrixanalysis.com/Chapter8.pdf)*, SIAM, ISBN 0-89871-454-0.

I found those books by searching the World Wide Web.  The search led me to a [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perron%E2%80%93Frobenius_theorem) and then to a list of books and articles in that article's reference section.